# Windows Server Backup Catalog corrupted

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-backup, wbadmin

I am facing this issue multiple times on my Windows 2008R2 Server. It is showing this error when I try to backup using wbadmin.
"Windows backup failed. Global Catalog Corrupted."

I tried restoring the catalog from old backups, and run >SFC /scannow But, when I try to backup, it becomes corrupted again.